# Embed specific video into html

Tags: html, video

I have this video http://flash.bc.edu/omc/other/guestbook/jerusalem2011.mp4 that I need to embed in an html web page. From looking at the source of the page it's currently on, I have this code:

```
<embed height="100%" width="100%" name="plugin"
src="http://flash.bc.edu/omc/other/guestbook/jerusalem2011.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</embed>
```

It won't show up at all if I put that code in to my other html page, even though I have changed the width and height to smaller sizes.
Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls"> <source src="http://flash.bc.edu/omc/other/guestbook/jerusalem2011.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" /> Browser cannot display this video</video>
```

Comment: Using firefox and safari, this still didn't help.